# Can a ban in South Africa affect my UK entry even with a job offer/sponsorship?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, overstay, south-africa

I traveled to South Africa back in 2018 and was involved in a car accident. Because I was receiving treatment there decided to apply for a visa extension which takes up to 2 months. I was denied and had to leave the country to which I received the ban upon exiting. I was told to submit an appeal at the embassy in my home country after I explained my situation why I had overstayed, to which I later realized needed documents I needed from the hospital I was being treated at. Unfortunately I had no one to collect said documents nor did I have the means to hire a lawyer at the time. That was all back in 2018. My ban is expiring this coming August.

What I want to know is, can this affect my UK visa application even a job sponsorship?

I'm from Malawi by the way.

Comment: Is this about a visitor visa for the UK or a longer term visa like for working there?

Comment: @Willeke the question refers to having a job offer and sponsor

Comment: There’s a chance it might, but provided you declare and explain the ban in your visa application, assuming you meet all the eligibility criteria and have the relevant sponsor IMHO it should not be an *automatic* negative. Especially if you have an otherwise clean travel history to other countries. Don’t be tempted not to declare it simply because it has expired though. Probably a good idea to let your sponsor know about it early on too, prospective employers tend not to like unpleasant surprises.

Comment: @Midavalo, it can be for just an interview rather than long term staying in the UK or something like that.

Comment: A longer term visa for work.